# Bar plot legend not displaying correctly

Tags: pgfplots, legend

In the legend for a bar plot that I'm building, I'm only getting a small tick next to the name, not a block of color. I'm not defining any special cycle lists. The code for the plot is:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{Comparison of Solutions}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xbar interval=0.7, height=400pt, width=3.25in, symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d,e}, ylabel={Number of Nodes}, xlabel={Number of Colors}, yticklabels={50,100,200,500,100}, legend style={cells={anchor=south west, inner xsep=0, inner ysep=0, fill}, nodes={inner sep=0}}]
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\colorseight};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\colorssixteen};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\colorsthirtytwo};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\dfseight};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\dfssixteen};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\dfsthirtytwo};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\comeight};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\comsixteen};
  \addplot table [x=colors, y=symb]{\comthirtytwo};
  \legend{DiMa2eD (4 links), DiMa2ed (8 links), DiMa2ed (16 links),4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{plo:colors}
\end{figure}
```

Each macro refers to a different tab deliniated file. Here is one that can be duplicated for experimenting.

```
nodes   colors  links   symb
50  178     16  a
100     176     16  b
200     177     16  c
500     183     16  d
500     183     16  e
```

and the preamble command to create the macro:

```
\pgfplotstableread{data/dfs.tab}\bestdfs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the option `area legend` to the `axis` options draws a little rectangle in the legend instead of a line segment (p. 120 in the [pgfplots manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf)).

With the `axis` options `legend style={cells={anchor=center, fill}, nodes={inner sep=1,below=-1.1ex}},area legend` and your example file I get

[image: Bar plot legend in pgfplots]